# Firebase do not create user in Unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

It is strange that Firebase can't create user in Unity SDK out of the box.
Firebase Console was tuned (anonymous access and email/password access are enabled) and google-service.json was placed in Assets folder of Unity.

However, Firebase still won't create a user. This is the code where it always fails:

```
auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.Log("User is now signed in.");
                FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log("User signup failed");
            }
        });
```

Why?

Answer (score 5):

There are possible several reasons:

- The app was run in the Editor, rather than **on the device**
- The configuration file is not updated after you add Firebase Auth feature
- The password is shorter than 6 chacters
- The email address is in invalid form, e.g. abcdef@aaa

The first one is highly likely the reason why.

I have created [a tutorial here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2017/01/22/using-firebase-in-unity3d-tutorial-2-authorization-and-user-login-example-with-user-name-and-password/), which covers the steps to create/login using firebase in Unity, hope this is helpful.

[image]

Comment: SIR! I swear by the holy potato I am going to buy a cookie.
The first one did was the problem . . .  


The google DOCZ is clearly shitty. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup?authuser=0)
The step 6 says

Click Switch Platform to select Android as the target platform.

Well, I did but it says NOWHERE it would not execute successfully in the Editor. I ran it like thousand times and thousand time I got the message the User was successfully created but I could never see it anywhere unless you 
 as you mentioned to actually deploy on a Device... thanks google wasting 50+ hours